# Реализация двух билдеров в одном классе

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, lombok

Пытаюсь реализовать два билдера для двух разных наборов параметров (тип набора определяется по полю type)

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
class SomeCode {

    private final String type;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String state;
    private int age;



    @Builder(builderMethodName = "oneBuilder")
        private static SomeCode one(@NonNull String firstName, @NonNull String lastName) {
        SomeCode one = new SomeCode("personal");
        one.firstName = firstName;
        one.lastName = lastName;
        return one;     
    }

    @Builder(builderMethodName = "twoBuilder")
        private static SomeCode two(@NonNull String state, int age) {
        SomeCode two = new SomeCode("date");
        two.state = state;
        two.age = age;
        return two;
    }   

}
```

Вызываю билдер:

```
SomeCode testCase = SomeCode.oneBuilder()
                .firstName("test")
                .lastName("two")
                .age(2)
                .build();
```

Как видно, в билдер_1 попадает параметр age, который соответствует билдеру_2.
Так-же у объекта testCase можно вызвать геттер параметра, который в билдер не попадает.

Что можно сделать с этим классом, что-бы параметры одного билдера не подмешивались в параметры второго билдера при создании объекта.

Второе - что можно сделать с геттерами, что-бы они были доступны только для своего билдера?

Comment: 3 билдера нужно. Абстрактный на самом верхнем уровне `AbstractBuilder`. В него войдут все поля и методы для твоих двух билдеров. И две имплементации `FirstBuilder extends AbstractBuilder` и `SecondBuilder extends AbstractBuilder`. В них уже включить свои методы которые разнятся друг с другом.

Comment: @maklas Если сделать наследование - то и тип данных измениться. + измениться сам процесс создания: вместо условного `SomeCode testCase = SomeCode.oneBuilder()`, будет OneBuilder testCase = OneBuilder.oneBuilder()